# Raspberry 2b lost Wifi connexion (using USB Wifi)

Tags: raspbian, wifi, usb

Yesterday i reinstalled my RPI 2B and 1B with the new Raspbian OS.
When i wanted to connect the RPI to my Wifi using a dongle USB Edimax and TP-LINK, it connect but after few seconds the RPI lost the connexion.
I saw with "iwconfig" that the link quality was between 20 and 40 on 100.

But with the same USB Wifi dongle, my computer was aible to use the wifi with a good speed. The RPI didn't arrived to charge a webpage.

Sorry for my english :)

And thanks if you can help me !

Comment: could be a power supply issue - what power supply are you using

Comment: A windows driver could be bundled with a different firmware.

Comment: I use a USB alim or USB powerbank who can deliver 4,8A.
And i didn't got driver with the product.